# asp.net mvc and webforms use two button

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, events, webforms

My problem is I'm trying do something to on mvc webforms

```
page name = addition.aspx 
event = button1_click
int numberOne = convert.toint32(textbox1.text);
int numberTwo = convert.toint32(textbox2.text);
int myResult = numberOne + numberTwo;
label1.text = myResult.Tostring();
```

.

```
page name = addition.aspx (same page) 
event = button2_click
int numberthree = convert.toint32(textbox3.text);
int numberfour = convert.toint32(textbox4.text);
int myResult2 = numberOne + numberTwo;
label2.text = myResult2.Tostring();
```

my question is I want to do sameting  for MVC ( where is event ... i guess i have to conversion on the page post and page get ... am i wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have server side controls for MVC. If you are wanting to have two buttons trigger different events you have a couple options. JQuery is included in your MVC project by default, and it's very popular. So I will show you some examples with that.

Create the two submit buttons to toggle the form action before submit.

Example using jquery:

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
   <input type="submit" id="first" value="first" />
   <input type="submit" id="second" value="second" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    // on document ready wire up click events  

    // handle click event for first button
    $('#first').on('click', function(){
         $('form').prop('action', 'PostActionOne'); // set the action on the form to handle first button post
    });
    // handle click event for second button
    $('#second').on('click', function(){
         $('form').prop('action', 'PostActionTwo'); // set the action on the form to handle second button post
    });
});
```

Another option:

Use two buttons with a click event that executes an ajax request to handle the scenario.

**HTML**

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    // on document ready wire up click events  
    $('#first').on('click', function(){
          $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'PostActionOne,
             data: data,
             success: success,
             dataType: dataType
         });
    });

    $('#second').on('click', function(){
          $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'PostActionTwo,
             data: data,
             success: success,
             dataType: dataType
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure first JS is currect? becouse i copy past yoru code is not workin can you send me your project .... realy i need solition becouse i want to use mvc anymore..

Comment: I didn't make a solution for your answer. I posted example code of how to handle it.

Comment: @MehmetHüseyinÖzcan You need to create your own solution - the answer is here for your reference. You have to put forth some amount of effort here - we do not spoon feed. Part of learning is doing things for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET WebPages indeed may offer better event driven programming(arguably), but nevertheless it does not run on the client side. So regardless if you use WebForms or MVC if you want something to take place on the click event of a button located on a browser webpage, make the triggers in javascript, jquery, and use ajax so you don`t have to reload the entire page each time.

Also in mvc you have a helper called

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("linkname", "Action", "etc");
```

that can get you working pretty fast, just read about it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: i am greatfull to your answer... tank you very much.